# Poner datos por defecto en Base de Datos Android

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos

Tengo como un especie de formulario de registro y me gustaria saber si por ejemplo si no pones nada como contraseña te ponga una contraseña por defecto.

Tengo así el método registro

```
    private void register(){
    String user = etuser.getText().toString();
    String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
    if(user.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
        displayToast("Usuario o contraseña vacio");
    }else{
        db.addUser(user,pass);
        displayToast("Usuario registrado con exito!");
        finish();
    }
}
```

Y metodo que añade a la base de datos

```
    public void addUser(String usurarios, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_usurarios, usurarios);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);

    long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Usuario insertado" + id);
}
```

Actualizado con COLUMN_ESTADO

```
    public void addUser(String usurarios, String password, String estado) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_usurarios, usurarios);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);
    values.put(COLUMN_ESTADO, estado);

    long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Usuario insertado" + id);
}
```

Metodo Registro

```
    private void register(){
    String user = etuser.getText().toString();
    String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
    String estado = Estado.getText().toString();
    if(user.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
        displayToast("Usuario o contraseña vacio");
    }
    else if (pass.isEmpty()){
        db.addUser(user,"1234",estado);
        displayToast("Usuario registrado con exito!");
        finish();
    }
    else if (estado.isEmpty()){
        db.addUser(user,pass,"Hola que tal");
    }
    else{
        db.addUser(user,pass,estado);
        displayToast("Usuario registrado con exito!");
        finish();
    }
}
```

Layout Registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ok, y cual es el problema? tu estás validando que la contraseña no sea vacía , porque no cambias la validación?

Comment: Tipo quiero que si la contraseña esta vacia que te añada una contraseña por defecto por ejmplo 1234 @diegoveloper

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, te sirve?

Comment: Eso es totalmente inseguro y no se debe hacer  ... como sabra el usuario su contraseña a menos que le envies un respaldo de su cuenta creada

Comment: La practica que nos mando el profesor dice que si no pones contraseña, el administrador le asignara uno por defecto en este caso "1234" @AshleyG.

Comment: bueno en ese caso no hay nada mas que hacer, pero en la vida del programador es una mala practica :p jaja

Comment: Cada vez que le doy a AÑADIR USUARIO se me peta. He añadido el estado. @diegoveloper

Comment: que es Estado? donde lo declaras

Comment: si agregaste una nueva columna a tu tabla, te recomiendo que por ahora desinstales la app y vuelves a instalarla, sino tendrías que hacer un fix que es un poco más largo cuando haces upgrade de database

Comment: Ok, he añadido una columna a mi tabla, pero en el layout de registro no tengo ningún text view de estado. Cada vez que creo un usuario me tendrá que poner un estado por defecto, y luego en otro layout tendré la posibilidad de cambiar el estado. He actualizado mi pregunta.@diegoveloper

Comment: tu pregunta ya fue resuelta, puedes crear otra en todo caso, igual ya te di la solución arriba en mis comentarios

Comment: Vale mejor creo una nueva pregunta, Mil gracias @diegoveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer así :

```
if(user.isEmpty()){
        displayToast("Usuario o contraseña vacio");
    }
else if (pass.isEmpty()){
       db.addUser(user,"1234");
        displayToast("Usuario registrado con exito!");
        finish();
}
else{
        db.addUser(user,pass);
        displayToast("Usuario registrado con exito!");
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Vava, me va ya. Una preguntilla. Tengo un campo llamado estado. Cada vez que me registro quiero que me ponga un estado por defecto ¿Seria igual?

Comment: usar finish() ?  Que pasa si el usuario es vacio. asignara una pass a un usuario vacio ...

Comment: si, claro, podrías usar una constante:  db.addUser(user,pass, "TU_ESTADO");

Comment: @zzxbx si te sirvió mi respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada para cerrar la pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de insertar valores por defecto es cambiando la definición de base de datos para no tener que estar validando campo por campo si viene vacio de la siguiente manera cuando creas la tabla:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tabla_usuarios
(usuario TEXT NOT NULL,
 clave TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '123456') ";
```