# Evitar usuarios duplicados Android Studio

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos

Tengo un método donde registra usuarios, bien, lo que quiero que si pongo un **nombre de usuario** igual que otro, me salga un mensaje que diga "*Usuario ya registrado con el mismo nombre*".

**Método Registro**:

```
private void register(){
    String user = etuser.getText().toString();
    String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
    if(user.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
        displayToast(getString(R.string.UsuarioVacio));
    } else if (pass.isEmpty()){
        db.addUser(user,"1234","");
        displayToast(getString(R.string.UsuarioExito) +
                getString(R.string.ContraseñaDefecto));
        finish();
    }
    else{
        db.addUser(user,pass,"");
        displayToast(getString(R.string.UsuarioExito2));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Clase addUser**:

```
    public void addUser(String usurarios, String password, String estado) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_usurarios, usurarios);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);
    values.put(COLUMN_ESTADO, "Tu estado");

    long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Usuario insertado" + id);
}
```

Comment: ¿ No era el mismo problema que el que se supone se resolvió aquí ? : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123135/poner-datos-por-defecto-en-base-de-datos-android

Comment: No, lo que quiero es por ejemplo te registras con un usuario "Jorge", pues ya si registras un usuario con el mismo nombre "Jorge" que diga "Usuario ya registrado, pruebe con otro" No se si me explico xd

Comment: La solucion mas sencilla es poner la columna que corresponde a ese dato de la base de datos como unique, asi la base de datos no aceptara duplicados, y te emitira un error, tu atrapas ese error y emites el mensaje.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún ejemplo? te lo agradecería mucho @eyllanesc

Comment: Pienso que debes intertar resolverlo, no es agradable ver que que muestres el mismo codigo de una pregunta anterior. Debes intentar, aunque te equivoques es la mejor forma de aprender.

Comment: También podés hacer una query para obtener si el usuario ya existe y si devuelve un resultado, entonces generás un error.

Comment: agregar tipo unique a los campos que lo requieran en tu tabla?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer esto, si es lo haces con base de datos en SQLite.

```
//HelperSql bd = new HelperSql(this);
SQLiteDatabase sql = this.getWritableDatabase();
String user = etuser.getText().toString();
if(!user.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()){
   Cursor fila = sql.rawQuery(
            "select user, from users where user=" + user, null);
   if (fila.moveToFirst()){
      Toast.makeText(this, "Ya existe este usuario",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else{
      db.addUser(user,pass,"");
      displayToast(getString(R.string.UsuarioExito2));
      finish();
   }
}
```

Comment: Me da varios errores.(Actualziado la pregunta)

Comment: que errores te da

Comment: El query es incorrecto, "user" es una cadena.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es colocar comillas simples (') para encerrar la entrada 'user' en el método rawQwery() porque 'user' es una cadena de texto, no una clave o un número entero. Edité la respuesta.